# Setting one class in raster symbology using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, symbology

Is it possible in QGIS to exclude some values from the symbology and define only 1 class with 1 color for all the other values?

I have hard time to find how to do it with the Singleband pseudocolor render type. It seems QGIS only allows 2 classes minimum (why not 1?) The problem is that the 2 classes appear in the legend afterward while in the legend I want only 1 class. I have a raster with values from 0 to 100 and I would like to exclude values from 0 to 29 and draw value from 30 to 100 in one green color.

In ArcGIS there is a convenient option where one can group certain values into one class at the symbology level (without touching anything in the original data).

Is there a way to produce he same effect in QGIS without reclassifying the data?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For some specific interval with one legend item, you can leave one class in *Symbology* and use configure *Transparency* setting (a bit workaround). In transparency settings you can exclude specific values (0 - 400 in my example):

[image]

If you need to display only 1 class with values less than defined, it can be done with **Discrete** interpolation (Value <= 500 in exaple):

[image]

Comment: This is incorrect, The OP wants to show the values of more than or equal certain values, what you are showing is the oppsite. You are showing the less that or equal. Have a look at the header of the classification, it shows `Value <=`.

Comment: Yes you are right, sorry I will edit my question.

Comment: The only way to remove the hidden class is from the legend from `Print composer -> Add legend -> Uncheck Auto update -> Select the hidden class and click on the red minus symbl (-)`, and the hidden class will be removed.

Comment: My solution is fixed. Yes, this is another approach (not only option) which only remove the class from legend, not from the map item (the data stay symbolized), so still you have to symbolize data with transparent/white color with *Discrete* interpolation.

Comment: +1 from me for having an efficient approach in simple way.